# How to get appWindow from Chrome.app.window.create

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to write a chrome.app that is able to open and close chrome.app windows on both displays of a system that is configured with two monitors.  When launched, the chrome application establishes a socket connection with a native application running on the same computer, I also open a hidden window via chrome.app.window.create to keep the chrome application up and running.  The native application then reads a configuration file and then sends a series of ‘openBrowser’ commands to the chrome application via the socket.
When the chrome application receives an ‘openBrowser’ command, the chrome application makes a call to the chrome API method chrome.app.window.create, passing the create parameters AND a callback function.  A code snippet is below:

```
NPMBrowserManager.prototype.openBrowser = function (browserId,htmlFile,browserBounds,hidden,grabFocus)
{
   var browserManager = this;
   var createParameters = {};

   createParameters.bounds = browserBounds;
   createParameters.hidden = hidden;

   chrome.app.window.create(htmlFile,createParameters,function(appWindow)
   {
      // Check to see if I got a non-undefined appWindow.
      if(appWindow !== null)
      {
         browserManager.browsers.push({"browserId":browserId,"window":appWindow});
         console.info("NPMBrowserManager.openBrowser: Added browser, id =" +    browserId + ", count =" + browserManager.browsers.length);
      }
   });
}
```

Unfortunately, the ‘appWindow’,  parameter passed in the create callback is always undefined.  I suspect it has something to do with the fact that the method openBrowser is itself being called by another method that processes commands received from the native application.  However, the window opens exactly here and when I want to to, I just can’t seem to cache away any information about the new window that can be used later to close or move the window.

I want to be able to cache away the appWindow so that I can close or modify the created window later on in the workflow.

As a side note,  I’ve noticed that appWindow is NOT undefined if I call the openBrowser method from within the callback that is associated with the chrome.app.runtime.onLaunched event.  I suspect it has something to do with the current script context.  I was not able to find any chrome.app documentation that goes into any detail about the chrome app architecture.

I would GREATLY appreciate it if anyone out there can explain to me how I can get the appWindow of the window that is created in the chrome.app.window.create method.  By the way, I have also tried calling chrome.app.window.current to no avail…  Very frustrating!!!

I’d also be interested in any documentation that might exist.  I am aware of developer.chrome.com, but could not find much documentation other than reference documentation.

Thanks for the help!

Jim

Comment: I suppose the missing left double-quote in `,window":appWindow` is just a typo in the question and not the cause of the problem, right ?

Comment: Yes, that is a rookie copy paste error, my code has the leading double quote, only wish it were that easy,,,  Thanks for looking at it!

Comment: (I bet you have, but...) have you tried putting a few `alert`s here and there and watch the actual execution flow ? E.g. does an `alert` in the callback for `create` show up at all (or is the callback never executed) ?

Comment: Well, I've used console.info, I'm assuming that works as well, and yes, the callback is indeed being called, but when called as a result of a command read from the socket, appWindow is always 'undefined'.  However if openBrowser is called from within the onLaunched event handler, the appWindow is valid (not undefined). Bottom line is I need some way of caching away the reference to the window that gets created so I can do 'stuff' to it later. Thanks again for the input, I'll check out alert.

Comment: If you have already tried `console.info`, then there is nothing more to see from an alert. This is really strange behaviour (and I am afraid there is not sufficient documentation out there to cover cases like this).